# How to get a list of users in an AD group that are also memebers of a second AD group with Power shell

Tags: powershell

I am very new to PowerShell and I unable to locate a way to perform the following task.

I need to list all users that are members of group A and then filer the results by membership of a group B

Get-memberof X group then show of that group users that are also members of y group

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Get the members of the first group and put them in a variable, do the same for the second group. Use the `Compare-Object` cmdlet to find objects that exist in both groups (specify the  -IncludeEqual switch):

```
Compare-Object $group1 $group2 -Property member -IncludeEqual | 
Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '=='}
```